# In List, How to modify the link edit to quick mode?

Tags: sharepoint-online

In List, How to modify the link edit that instead of sending to Quick Mode Edit to send that to InfoPath costumised form? Or add another one? ie **new item** or **edit** or **edit InfoPath**? [image]

Comment: You can make the custom InfoPath form the default new form.

Comment: Already done that, how to change the edit link though?